# Making a rectangle within another rectangle and positioning elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to code a resume template just to learn the basics about HTML and CSS. However I have a problem when it comes to positioning a rectangle inside another one. I have been searching for hours and how to fix this but not sure why it isn't appearing at all. I wanted the rectangle to appear over the blue one but under the "Name" text as like a highlighting bar.

I believe it has to do with how I am positioning my elements. I tried using z-index as well but none of the changes I am making is working.

Also as a quick follow up, I wanted to know why I can't align the text "Name" in the center of my rectangle. I tried doing text-align:center but that doesn't do anything either. I feel like I am missing a major concept here with both of these problems. Any insight would be appreciated.

I pasted the code I am working with here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lx09fvcw/1/

Specifically this HTML part:

```
<svg class = "leftBar">
    <rect id="leftRec">
        <div class="Name">Name</div>
        <div class = "icon">
            <img src ="img/education.png">
        </div>
    </rect>

    <rect id = "rightRec"></rect>

</svg>
```

As an edit I originally wanted a rectangle above another one like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKaJp.jpg

I am trying to align everything inside an A4 Size Page, but the blue rectangle has a gap between the leftmost part of the A4 page. Since I am not allowed to use absolute, I would just like some insight into how to do that because nothing is working that I am trying online. Not asking for someone to implement it for me but just show me the way as it is a bit confusing. Thanks for the help

Current code: http://jsfiddle.net/05p9qo7t/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind you can't directly append `div` as a child to `rect`, `circle`, and `path`. You just can do it with `foreignObject`, but I strongly not recommend that way.

But if you insist on such a thing you can check the `foreignObject` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

If you want to create a resume template in another way I can share some code for you for better illustration.

**EDIT:**

Here is an alternative solution for what you looking for, check the code snippet below:

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container>div.right-rect {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #003d73;
}

.container>div.right-rect>span.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.container>div.right-rect>span.name,
.container>div.right-rect>div.icon {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-rect">
    <span class="name">Name</span>
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="img/education.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-rect"></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I just use `100vh` and `100vw` to fit every viewport, you can replace them with any suitable value.

**Implementing left rectangle without `position: absolute;`**

To avoid using `position: absolute;`, first of all, you should wrap all your element in your related parent, so you need to move

```
<div class="over-rect"></div>
```

and

```
<span class="name">Name</span>
```

to the related parent where in our case it is `div` with `blue-rect` class, then since we used pseudo-class styling we should modify some of our styles to make items fit the new position in the flow. After that we should get rid of `position: absolute;` and replace them with `relative` one.

> This is optional and better for responsive designs in case you don't care about these stuffs you can keep up with absolute positioning.

But we also must do some modification in the flow with modifying the `top` element of items positioned relatively, so we add a `top` element to our style to move relative items with respect to their parent positioning.

Check out the code revises below:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container>div.blue-rect {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #003d73;
}

.container>div.blue-rect>div.over-rect {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 3%;
  background-color: red;
}

.container>div.blue-rect>span.name {
  position: relative;
  top: -18px;
  z-index: 20;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.container>div.blue-rect>div.icon {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.education {
  width: 60px;
  height: auto;
}

page[size="A4"] {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@media print {
  body,
  page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="blue-rect">
      <div class="over-rect"></div>
      <span class="name">Name</span>
      <div class="icon">
        <img class="education" src="img/education.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</page>
```

Comment: But if I put the div outside the rect class it ends up pushing the object elsewhere without being on top right? Should I just be positioning everything in the svg object relative to each other instead of stacking them?

Comment: Honestly, there is no need to creating `svg` for such a simple `div`, for knowing when to use `svg` I suggest you read [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Comment: @BillTaha You can check my alternative answer for what you wanted.

Comment: #SMAKSS

thanks for the insight. Learned a good deal from it for aligning things. Also with your implementation, making the container position relative, the rectangle position:absolute, made it so I can have a rectangle above another one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BillTaha You better not to be using position absolute where there is a possibility to make an alternative solution, you can tell me what you exactly want to do or picture of desire one, to help me guide you on this one. Also, make sure if any answer here is the exact fit for your problem you have to mark them as an answer to help the other community member got a better experience.

Comment: sorry about that I will make sure to do that once this is fixed. I am trying to do something like this. https://imgur.com/a/eOUGT8n 

Where there is a rectangle ontop of another rectangle. I can only do this with absolute though. Also I am trying to make them all in a Page A4 div. The code I am using right now looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/05p9qo7t/1/ There is still some alignment issues with the name along with aligning the blue rectangle to the edge of the A4 paper as it appears to have a left-margin even though I don't see it anywhere in the CSS. @SMAKSS

Comment: @BillTaha Sorry for the bother, I just make a little modification for what did you shared in the last comment, you can check it out in the answer edit.